# Why is the question valid? How can I make sense of it?

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving, real-numbers

I am solving exercise from Terence Tao's Analysis- Vol 1. One of the exercise was-
Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Show that $x\leq y+\varepsilon$ for
all real numbers $\varepsilon > 0$ if and only if $x\leq y$. Show that $|x- y|\leq \varepsilon$ for all
real numbers $\varepsilon > 0$ if and only if $x = y$.
How can $x\leq y+\varepsilon$ be true when $x\leq y$, wont it be $x<y+\varepsilon$? And the second part too, if $x=y$ won't it be $|x-y|=0$?
What am I not understanding here?
Is it because $x$ and $y$ are real numbers? because he defines real numbers as-
A real number is defined to
be an object of the form $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$, where $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is a Cauchy
sequence of rational numbers.

Comment: If $x<y+\epsilon$ then we certainly have $x≤y+\epsilon$.  Strong inequality implies weak inequality.

Comment: Sure on one side it is obvious, if $x\leq y$, then $x<y+\epsilon$ and then clearly $x\leq y+\epsilon$. But the converse is interesting. Again, for the second part proving that if  $|x-y| \leq \epsilon$, then $x=y$ is more interesting because converse is obvious.

Comment: i am sorry but i still dont get it, if for any x it is always less than $y+\epsilon$ how can it ever have a value equal to $y+\epsilon$

Comment: Yes. That is the semantics of $\leq$. We have $2\leq 2$ but also $1\leq 2$. You could say how could 1 ever be equal to 2? But the statement just says 1 is lesser than or equal to 2. Which is true. The statement $x\leq y$ is true even if we are sure that $x<y$.

Comment: then why is it "......if and only if $x\leq y$" which means if $x<y$ the statement $x\leq y+\epsilon$ be false since its true because it will be less?

Comment: I think you have sort of gone down a little bit of a rabbit hole. You might look at my answer below which gives a full proof of the claim, if you want to dot your i's and cross your t's.

Comment: $x<y$ is not a condition that violates $x\leq y$ but is included in it. In fact $x<y\implies x\leq y$
Read it like this "......if and only if x is either equal or less than y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \leq y$, then certainly $x \leq y + \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

If $x > y$, then set $\delta = x - y > 0$. Then if $\epsilon = \delta/2 > 0$, say, we see that $$y + \epsilon = (x - 2 \epsilon) + \epsilon = x - \epsilon < x.$$

Therefore we proved

> $x \leq y$ if and only if $x \leq y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $x = |u - v|$ and $y = 0$. Then we also see as a corollary:

> $|u - v| \leq 0$ if and only if $|u - v| \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $|u -v| \geq 0$,  we see that $|u - v| \leq 0$ is equivalent to $|u - v| = 0$ or equivalently $u = v$. Therefore, we can equivalently state:

> $u =v$ if and only if $|u - v| \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.